# add same content for a entire column in r

Tags: r

I have a table with 3000+ rows, and I want to add same content for a entire column.

```
> head(zld)
 chr    start  end position summit
Uextra 181104 181729 181199    198
3R 12619 125748 126256    190
2L 20705 207716 207753    185
3R  2579  26014  26353    184
3R 12642 126368 12635    180
3R 12534 1254 12917    179
```

I want to add "chr" to the column chr, like this

```
> head(zld)
 chr    start  end position summit
chrUextra 181104 181729 181199    198
chr3R 12619 125748 126256    190
chr2L 20705 207716 207753    185
chr3R  2579  26014  26353    184
chr3R 12642 126368 12635    180
chr3R 12534 1254 12917    179
```

Thank you for any advise!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paste`:

```
zld$chr = paste0("chr", zld$chr)

#        chr  start    end position summit
#1 chrUextra 181104 181729   181199    198
#2     chr3R  12619 125748   126256    190
#3     chr2L  20705 207716   207753    185
#4     chr3R   2579  26014    26353    184
#5     chr3R  12642 126368    12635    180
#6     chr3R  12534   1254    12917    179
```

Here, `paste0` omits a separator and is equivalent to `paste(str1, str2, sep="")`